# How to create a link that goes back in react-router-dom v4

Tags: react-router

I know I can access `history.goBack()` to go back in the router history.

However, I'd like to create a `<Link />` tag that has this functionality and relies on the `to` property (href) to navigate back rather than an onClick.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have a solution to your problem using the `context` api.
**But I strongly believe that it would be easier to use history.goBack().**

First you'll need to wrap the `App` component inside a router:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Then in your your `App/index.js` file you'll need to listen to the location change event and set your state accordingly:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {
  state = { prevLocation: '' };

  // Use the context api to retrieve the value in your Link
  getChildContext = () => (
    {
      prevLocation: this.state.prevLocation,
    }
  );

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
     this.setState({ prevLocation: this.props.location.pathname });
   }
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Switch>
         // ...
       </Switch>
     </div>
   );
  }
}

App.childContextTypes = {
  prevLocation: PropTypes.string,
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

Then in can create a `GoBack` component and use the context API to retrieve the value the previous path.

```
import React from 'react';
class GoBack extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Link to={this.context.prevLocation}>click</Link);
  }
}

GoBack.contextTypes = {
  prevLocation: PropTypes.string,
};
```